# OData always returns `{}` for entity JsonDocument property

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, microsoft.aspnetcore.odata

I have an entity with an column which was scaffolded as a `JsonDocument`. When rendering via OData this entity property always renders as an empty object, `{}`.

When inspecting the data, or viewing the raw object itself, the data is present.  I do have to use `Attributes.RootElement` to see it though, of course - but `AspNetCoreOData` uses the `JsonDocument` class internally too, so it isn't foreign.

Do I need to register a converter, or otherwise enable OData to handle this kind of column correctly? So far googling by any combination of keywords turns up very little, and all of that is around strongly typed JSON columns.
Entity

```
[Table("product")]
public class Product : IDisposable
{
    [Key, Column("id")] public long Id { get; set; }
    [Column("attributes")] public JsonDocument Attributes { get; set; } = null!;
    ... 
    public void Dispose() => Attributes.Dispose();
}
```

##### OData Results for a single product

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:7277/...",
    "Attributes": {},
    "Id": 1,
    ...
}
```

##### Entity Framework Query

```
var ent = Entities.Where(o => o.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(ent?.Attributes.RootElement.ToString());
>>> {"age": "really old"}
```

##### Assembly Versions

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v8.1.2
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v7.05
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v7.0.4
- PostgreSQL 14